# how to change comment author's link from user's website to author's page(author.php)?

Tags: comments

I am making theme.
and in my custom post type comment,  I using

```
wp_list_comments( array(
    'style'       => 'div',
    'short_ping'  => true,
    'avatar_size' => 0,
    'reply_text'  => 'reply',
) );
```

This works good. but, when I click the user's name(who wrote the comment), this makes move to his website. But I want to move to his author's page(author.php).

Is this possible? Can you give me some help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

### Using `callback` param

One of methods would be [using the `callback`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments#Comments_Only_With_A_Custom_Comment_Display) param of `wp_list_comments`.

This function takes 3 params: `$comment`, `$args` and `$depth` and using it you can create custom HTML code for comments.

There is an example showing how to use this callback in Codex or you can find such callbacks in TwentyX themes.

### Using `get_comment_author_url` filter

But if you want to modify only the URL for authors, then there's an easier and cleaner way and I would definitely prefer this solution.

You can use `get_comment_author_url` filter as showed below:

```
function use_author_link_as_comment_author_url( $url, $id, $comment ) {
    if ( $comment->user_id ) {
        return get_author_posts_url( $comment->user_id );
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_url', 'use_author_link_as_comment_author_url', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. This is really that I need and works good. I hope you have a cool  week.